# Batch file to delete temp files on a remote workstation

Tags: file, batch-file, temp

I wrote an easy batch to basically ask me a server name and then it would go and delete the temp files out of the specified directories. Yes I know power shell would probably be way more effective but Im still pretty new to my Sysadmin position and the network is so large Im not ready to be mingling in that area yet.

But anyway I would love to be able to create a list of the servers and have it go through them all deleting these temp files instead of opening a new command window for each server and then executing my batch file. I either want to have the list of servers already in the batch file or have the batch call back to .txt file with the server list and then open a brand new cmd prompt window for each server and commence the deletion.

Here is what I have so far, Its simple, its easy, it works, but Im coming across imputing about 100 servers so that's about 6 command prompt windows at a time (to avoid confusion) letting them go through and delete and when they all finish open another 6 give them all another server then let them delete and ETC

```
:deleteit
echo off
echo ------------------------------------------------------

set /p server=Please enter the name of your workstation/server you wish to clean:

echo You have entered %server% as your workstation

pause

del "\\%server%\c$\temp\*.*" /s /f /q

del "\\%server%\c$\windows\temp\*.*" /s /f /q

del "\\%server%\c$\windows\ProPatches\Patches\*.*" /s /f /q

rd /s "\\%server%\c$\$Recycle.bin"

echo --------------------------------------------------

set /p choice=Again? (y/n)

if /i %choice%==Y (goto deleteit) else (goto end)

:end
```